# Two DIVs beside each other without wrapper

Tags: html, alignment

I am currently going nuts while I am trying to get something to work.

I created a small website out of fun and to play around with  but I encounter one thing which is bugging me quite a lot.

This is the HTML which I have come up with:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="header">
  <div id="cover-cloud">
   <div id="cloud" class="cloud stage"></div>
   <div id="cloud2" class="cloud2 stage"></div>
   <div id="cloud3" class="cloud3 stage"></div>
   <div id="cloud4" class="cloud4 stage"></div>
   <div id="heading"><h1>Website</h1></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Imprint</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contac</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="lang">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="?lang=de"><img src="images/lang/de.gif" alt="DE"></a></li>
   <li><a href="?lang=en"><img src="images/lang/en.gif" alt="EN"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="content" class="clearfix">
  <div id="maincontent">
   <div class="contentblock">
    <h3>Home</h3>
     <p>Some welcome text or maybe news, who knows :)</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">Some footer content</div>
 <div id="valid">
  <ul>
   <li>Here comes the HTML validation thingy</li>
   <li>Here comes the CSS validation thingy</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="social">
 <div id="facebook"><img src="images/icons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></div>
 <div id="twitter"><img src="images/icons/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></div>
 <div id="youtube"><img src="images/icons/youtube.png" alt="YouTube"></div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to have the social DIV on the right hand side of the container DIV. My understanding was, that the social DIV is now taking on it's measurements from the container DIV and not from the left hand side of the screen? But it seems that my understanding was totally incorrect :(

This is the CSS of both DIV containers: (which only work on the main page, but when I click on a link, the social DIV jumps to the bottom left again)

```
#container { width: 800px; margin: 25px auto 5px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; position: relative; }

#social { margin: -154px 0 0; overflow: hidden; width: 45px; }
```

I also tried a few examples of some answers on here but they are not showing the right result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block elements (like divs) take the with of their parent element, and always start with line break. It's not enough to give a width to block element, you must tell it to stay on the same line. You can do that by floating:

```
#social {
    float: left;
}
```

Or you can make both divs inline-block elements:

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
}

#social {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

These two approaches have different drawbacks, but that's the other story.

Comment: Thank you, Zemljoradnik! I tried the inline-blocks as the float is not doing what it should do but that is as you said a drawback. Now however the container is not showing in the middle of the page anymore despite using the right margin.

Comment: Sorted it now. I just added <center></center> around the containers and that did the trick.